# Use Flask's "app" singleton to Dask Scheduler/Workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, dask, dask-distributed

**The Case:**

We have some time-consuming functional/integration tests that utilize Flask's `current_app` for configuration (global variables etc.) and some logging.
We are trying to distribute and parallelize those tests on a cluster (for the moment a local "cluster" created from [Dask's Docker image](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/docker.html).).

**The Issue(s?):**

Let's assume the following example:

A time-consuming function:

```
def will_take_my_time(n)
    # Add the 'TAKE_YOUR_TIME' in the config in how many seconds you want
    time.sleep(current_app.config['TAKE_YOUR_TIME'])
    return n
```

A time-consuming test:

```
def need_my_time_test(counter=None):
    print(f"Test No. {will_take_my_time(counter)}")
```

A Flask CLI command that creates a Dask [`Client`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/client.html) to connect to the cluster and execute 10 tests of `need_my_time_test`:

```
@app.cli.command()
def itests(extended):
    with Client(processes=False) as dask_client:
        futures = dask_client.map(need_my_time_test, range(10))
        print(f"Futures: {futures}")
        print(f"Gathered: {dask_client.gather(futures)}")
```

**EDIT:** For convenience let's add an application factory for an easier reproducible example:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DEBUG=True,
    )

    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    @app.cli.command()
    def itests(extended):
        with Client(processes=False) as dask_client:
            futures = dask_client.map(need_my_time_test, range(10))
            print(f"Futures: {futures}")
            print(f"Gathered: {dask_client.gather(futures)}")
```

Using the above with `flask itests`, we are running into the following error (described [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/)):

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
>   needed to interface with the current application object in some way.
>   To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().

We have tried:

- Pushing the `app_context` (`app.app_context().push()`) on the app singleton creation.
- Using `with current_app.app_context():` on the CLI command and some of the functions that use the `current_app`.
- Sending the `app_context` through a Dask [`Variable`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html?highlight=Variable#global-variables) but it cannot serialize the context.

With no avail.

**The questions:**

- Are there any suggestions on what should we try (containing the "where" will be highly appreciated)?
- Is there something that we tried correct but misused and we should retry it differently?

Comment: You might try creating the Cluster outside of a function and instead, in the route/cli connect to.  

If you can get a minimal reproducible example I can take a look at what you are doing

Comment: Do you use application factory?

Comment: @quasiben If you compose the example I am providing, you have everything you need to recreate the issue (I have done as much in a test project)

Comment: @fedepad yes I will add it on the initial question.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis it's a lot easier for me to test if I copy paste a working example.  Perhaps you can provide a gist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `current_app` proxy, it is assumed that the Flask app is created in the same process that the proxy is used.

This is not the situation when tasks submitted to the workers are run.
The tasks are executed isolated away from the Flask app created in the process that submitted the tasks.

In the task, define the flask app and provide the application context there.

```py
import time

from flask import Flask
from dask.distributed import Client


def _create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DEBUG=True,
        TAKE_YOUR_TIME=0.2
    )
    return app

def will_take_my_time(n):
    # Add the 'TAKE_YOUR_TIME' in the config in how many seconds you want
    app = _create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        time.sleep(app.config['TAKE_YOUR_TIME'])
    return n

def need_my_time_test(counter=None):
    print(f"Test No. {will_take_my_time(counter)}")

def create_app():
    app = _create_app()

    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    @app.cli.command()
    def itests():
        with Client(processes=False) as dask_client:
            futures = dask_client.map(need_my_time_test, range(10))
            print(f"Futures: {futures}")
            print(f"Gathered: {dask_client.gather(futures)}")
    return app

app = create_app()
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I solved it by creating a configuration dict before the singleton creation and passing that to the `app` and the tests as well, but with your point, I can reconsider!

Comment: That's much a better approach if you consider that you may not require capabilties of the `app` in your tests.